# How to convert minutes, seconds and miliseconds to zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this format of date in SQL Server

```
2017-08-24 08:04:42.560
```

I need to convert to this format

```
2017-08-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: When you say "convert" does that mean you are trying to update the dates to remove the time, or change their data type?   Or do you mean that you want to select them with just the day and no time?

Comment: Make it a date only and then add time 00:00:00. But it's unclear why you wish to do this

Answer (score 3):

Just convert to a date:

```
select cast(val as date)
```

If you want it back as a date/time (with the time component):

```
select cast(cast(val as date) as datetime)
```